Interrupt setup for waking up MSP430FR6889 from Low power mode using BMI160 Accelerometer
I am trying to setup an interrupt for waking up MSP430FR6889 from Low power mode using BMI160 Accelerometer. I want to operate my MSP430FR6889 in low power mode, until and unless BMI160 detects an acceleration of more than 1.2g, then MSP430FR6889 should wake up and show data on Code composer studio console until accelerometer stop detecting accelerations more than 1.2g.
I have so far got a code for MSP430FR6889, which reads the BMI160 and display the acceleration values on console but I need help to setup interrupt. Below is my code:
#define GLOBAL_Q    15
#include "QmathLib.h"
#include <msp430.h> 
#include "driverlib.h"
#include "DSPLib.h"
#include <gpio.h>
#include <intrinsics.h>
#include <msp430fr5xx_6xxgeneric.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>


//new
//#include "myClocks.h"
//new

//******************************************************************************
// Defines *********************************************************************
//******************************************************************************
//Address if the BMI160
#define SLAVE_ADDR 0x69
//Maximum I2C buffer size
#define MAX_BUFFER_SIZE 20

//Number of FFT samples
#define SAMPLES 10

/* Declare as persistent to move variable from RAM to FRAM */
#pragma PERSISTENT(input)
int16_t input[SAMPLES] = {0}; //Store samples


//new

#define UP              0x0010                          // Timer_A Up mode
#define CONTINUOUS      0x0020                          // Timer_A Continuous mode
#define ACLK            0x0100                          // Timer_A SMCLK source
#define DEVELOPMENT     0x5A80                          // Stop the watchdog timer
#define BOUNCE_DELAY    0xA000                          // Delay for Button Bounce
#define MS_10           400                             // Approximate value to count for 10ms
#define SMCLK           0x0200                          // Timer_A SMCLK source

//new

//******************************************************************************
// Timer Functions *************************************************************
//******************************************************************************

int delay(int count)
{
    if(TA1CTL & TAIFG)                                  // If Timer_1 is done counting
    {
        count = count-1;                                        // Decrement count
        TA1CTL = TA1CTL & (~TAIFG);                             // Reset Timer_1
    }
    return count;                                       // Return the value of count
} // end delay
//******************************************************************************
// UART Functions **************************************************************
//******************************************************************************
void UART_transmitString( char *pStr ) //Transmits a string over UART0
{
    while( *pStr )
    {
        while(!(UCA0IFG&UCTXIFG));
        UCA0TXBUF = *pStr;
        pStr++;
    }
}

//******************************************************************************
// I2C Functions ***************************************************************
//******************************************************************************
typedef enum I2C_ModeEnum{
    IDLE_MODE,
    NACK_MODE,
    TX_REG_ADDRESS_MODE,
    RX_REG_ADDRESS_MODE,
    TX_DATA_MODE,
    RX_DATA_MODE,
    SWITCH_TO_RX_MODE,
    SWITHC_TO_TX_MODE,
    TIMEOUT_MODE
} I2C_Mode;

/* Used to track the state of the software state machine*/
I2C_Mode MasterMode = IDLE_MODE;

uint8_t TransmitRegAddr = 0; //Register address for transmission
uint8_t ReceiveBuffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE] = {0}; //Buffer for received values
uint8_t RXByteCtr = 0; //Count received bytes
uint8_t ReceiveIndex = 0; //Index of received data
uint8_t TransmitBuffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE] = {0}; //Buffer for transmitted values
uint8_t TXByteCtr = 0; //Count transmitted bytes
uint8_t TransmitIndex = 0; //Index of transmitted data

void CopyArray(uint8_t *source, uint8_t *dest, uint8_t count)
{
    uint8_t copyIndex = 0;
    for (copyIndex = 0; copyIndex < count; copyIndex++)
    {
        dest[copyIndex] = source[copyIndex];
    }
}

I2C_Mode I2C_Master_ReadReg(uint8_t dev_addr, uint8_t reg_addr, uint8_t count)
{
    //printf("R\n");
    /* Initialize state machine */
    MasterMode = TX_REG_ADDRESS_MODE;
    TransmitRegAddr = reg_addr;
    RXByteCtr = count;
    TXByteCtr = 0;
    ReceiveIndex = 0;
    TransmitIndex = 0;

    /* Initialize slave address and interrupts */
    UCB1I2CSA = dev_addr;
    UCB1IFG &= ~(UCTXIFG + UCRXIFG);       // Clear any pending interrupts
    UCB1IE &= ~UCRXIE;                       // Disable RX interrupt
    UCB1IE |= UCTXIE;                        // Enable TX interrupt

    UCB1CTLW0 |= UCTR + UCTXSTT;             // I2C TX, start condition
    __bis_SR_register(LPM0_bits + GIE);              // Enter LPM0 w/ interrupts
 //   UCB1IE &= ~UCRXIE;                       // Disable RX interrupt


    return MasterMode;

}

I2C_Mode I2C_Master_WriteReg(uint8_t dev_addr, uint8_t reg_addr, uint8_t *reg_data, uint8_t count)
{
    /* Initialize state machine */
    MasterMode = TX_REG_ADDRESS_MODE;
    TransmitRegAddr = reg_addr;

    //Copy register data to TransmitBuffer
    CopyArray(reg_data, TransmitBuffer, count);

    TXByteCtr = count;
    RXByteCtr = 0;
    ReceiveIndex = 0;
    TransmitIndex = 0;

    /* Initialize slave address and interrupts */
    UCB1I2CSA = dev_addr;
    UCB1IFG &= ~(UCTXIFG + UCRXIFG);       // Clear any pending interrupts
    UCB1IE &= ~UCRXIE;                       // Disable RX interrupt
    UCB1IE |= UCTXIE;                        // Enable TX interrupt

    UCB1CTLW0 |= UCTR + UCTXSTT;             // I2C TX, start condition
    __bis_SR_register(LPM0_bits + GIE);              // Enter LPM0 w/ interrupts
    //printf("W\n");
    return MasterMode;
}

//******************************************************************************
// BMI160 Functions ************************************************************
//******************************************************************************
void bmi160_init(char FOC_axis)
{
    uint8_t writeData[1];
    //Read Chip ID, which is D1
    I2C_Master_ReadReg(SLAVE_ADDR, 0x00, 1);
    if(ReceiveBuffer[0] != 0xD1)
    {
        UART_transmitString(" Incorrect sensor chip ID ");
        printf("Incorrect sensor chip ID\n");
    }




    //Configure the accelerometer
    writeData[0]=0b00101100; //Set acc_us to 0 for off, and acc_bwp must then be 010. Set acc_odr to 1011(800Hz),1100(1600Hz),1000(100Hz),0001(25/32Hz)
    I2C_Master_WriteReg(SLAVE_ADDR, 0x40, writeData, 1);
    //Check if configuration worked
    I2C_Master_ReadReg(SLAVE_ADDR, 0x40, 1);
    if(ReceiveBuffer[0] != writeData[0])
    {
        UART_transmitString(" Accelerometer config failed ");
        printf("Accelerometer config failed\n");
    }
    //Set the range of the accelerometer
    writeData[0]=0b1000; //0b0011 for 2g, 0b0101 for 4g, 0b1000 for 8g
    I2C_Master_WriteReg(SLAVE_ADDR, 0x41, writeData, 1);
    //Check if range is set
    I2C_Master_ReadReg(SLAVE_ADDR, 0x41, 1);
    if(ReceiveBuffer[0] != writeData[0])
    {
        UART_transmitString(" Accelerometer range set failed ");
        printf("Accelerometer range set failed\n");
    }


    //Set the Accelerometer to normal power mode
    writeData[0] = 0x11;
    I2C_Master_WriteReg(SLAVE_ADDR, 0x7E, writeData, 1);
    //Read power mode status of sensors
    I2C_Master_ReadReg(SLAVE_ADDR, 0x03, 1);
    if(ReceiveBuffer[0] != 0x10)
    {
        UART_transmitString(" Accelerometer not on ");
        printf("Accelerometer not on\n");
    }

    //Fast Offset Compensation (FOC) setup

    //0 for reserved, 0 for gyroscope, 00 for x, 00 for y, 0 for z (10 = -1g, 00 = 0g, 01 = 1g)
    switch(FOC_axis)
    {
        case 'X':
            writeData[0] = 0b00100000;
            break;
        case 'Y':
            writeData[0] = 0b00001000;
            break;
        case 'Z':
            writeData[0] = 0b00000010;
            break;
        default:
            writeData[0] = 0b00000000; //Default of all 0g
            break;
    }
    I2C_Master_WriteReg(SLAVE_ADDR, 0x69, writeData, 1);
    //Check FOC
    I2C_Master_ReadReg(SLAVE_ADDR, 0x69, 1);
    if(ReceiveBuffer[0] != writeData[0])
    {
        UART_transmitString(" FOC not set ");
        printf("Incorrect sensor chip ID\n");
    }
    //Start FOC
    writeData[0] = 0x03;
    I2C_Master_WriteReg(SLAVE_ADDR, 0x7E, writeData, 1);
    //Wait until FOC is finished
    int finish = 0;
    while(finish==0)
    {
        I2C_Master_ReadReg(SLAVE_ADDR, 0x1B, 1);
        if((ReceiveBuffer[0] & 0b00001000) == 0b00001000)
        {
            finish = 1;
        }
    }
    //Enable offset compensation
    writeData[0] = 0b01000000; //Enable accelerometer offset compensation
    I2C_Master_WriteReg(SLAVE_ADDR, 0x77, writeData, 1);
    //Check offset compensation
    I2C_Master_ReadReg(SLAVE_ADDR, 0x77, 1);
    if(ReceiveBuffer[0] != writeData[0])
    {
        UART_transmitString(" Offset not enabled ");
        printf("Incorrect sensor chip ID\n");
    }
    //UART_transmitString(" BMI160 Initialized \n");
}



//******************************************************************************
// Device Initialization *******************************************************
//******************************************************************************
void initGPIO()
{
    /* Terminate all GPIO pins to Output LOW to minimize power consumption */

    // I2C pins (P4.0 is SDA, P4.1 is SCL)
    P4SEL1 |= BIT0 | BIT1;
    P4SEL0 &= ~(BIT0 | BIT1);

    // Configure P3.4 and P3.5 to UART (Primary, TX and RX respectively) for NeoCortec
    P3SEL0 |= BIT4 | BIT5;                    // USCI_A1 UART operation
    P3SEL1 &= ~(BIT4 | BIT5);                 // SEL1 is 0 and SEL0 is 1 for primary operation, inverse for secondary

    // Configure P2.0 and P2.1 to UART (Primary, TX and RX respectively) for PC
    P2SEL0 |= BIT0 | BIT1;                    // USCI_A0 UART operation
    P2SEL1 &= ~(BIT0 | BIT1);                 // SEL1 is 0 and SEL0 is 1 for primary operation, inverse for secondary

    // Disable the GPIO power-on default high-impedance mode to activate
    // previously configured port settings
    PM5CTL0 &= ~LOCKLPM5;
    __bis_SR_register(GIE);
}

void initClockTo16MHz()
{
    // Configure one FRAM waitstate as required by the device datasheet for MCLK
    // operation beyond 8MHz _before_ configuring the clock system.
    FRCTL0 = FRCTLPW | NWAITS_1;

    // Clock System Setup
    CSCTL0_H = CSKEY_H;                     // Unlock CS registers
    CSCTL1 = DCOFSEL_0;                     // Set DCO to 1MHz

    // Set SMCLK = MCLK = DCO, ACLK = VLOCLK (9.4kHz)
    CSCTL2 = SELA__VLOCLK | SELS__DCOCLK | SELM__DCOCLK;

    // Per Device Errata set divider to 4 before changing frequency to
    // prevent out of spec operation from overshoot transient
    CSCTL3 = DIVA__4 | DIVS__4 | DIVM__4;   // Set all corresponding clk sources to divide by 4 for errata
    CSCTL1 = DCOFSEL_4 | DCORSEL;           // Set DCO to 16MHz

    // Delay by ~10us to let DCO settle. 60 cycles = 20 cycles buffer + (10us / (1/4MHz))
    __delay_cycles(60);
    CSCTL3 = DIVA__32 | DIVS__1 | DIVM__1;  // Set ACLK to 239.75Hz, SMCLK to 16MHz, and MCLK to 16MHz
    CSCTL0_H = 0;                           // Lock CS registers
}

void initI2C()
{
    UCB1CTLW0 = UCSWRST;                      // Enable SW reset
    UCB1CTLW0 |= UCMODE_3 | UCMST | UCSSEL__SMCLK | UCSYNC; // I2C master mode, SMCLK
    UCB1BRW = 160;                            // fSCL = ACLK/160 = ~100kHz
    UCB1I2CSA = SLAVE_ADDR;                   // Slave Address
    UCB1CTLW0 &= ~UCSWRST;                    // Clear SW reset, resume operation
    UCB1IE |= UCNACKIE;
}

void UART_init(void)
{
    // Configure USCI_A1 for UART mode
    UCA1CTLW0 = UCSWRST;                      // Put eUSCI in reset
    UCA1CTLW0 |= UCSSEL__SMCLK;               // CLK = SMCLK
    UCA1BR0 = 8;                              // Clock prescaler set to 8
    UCA1BR1 = 0x00;                           // High byte empty, low byte is 8
    UCA1MCTLW |= UCOS16 | UCBRF_10 | 0xF700;  // Over-sampling on, first modulation register set to 10, second modulation register set to 0xF7 (247) for high byte, 0 for low byte
    UCA1CTLW0 &= ~UCSWRST;                    // Initialize eUSCI
    UCA1IE |= UCRXIE;                         // Enable USCI_A1 RX interrupt

    // Configure USCI_A0 for UART mode
    UCA0CTLW0 = UCSWRST;                      // Put eUSCI in reset
    UCA0CTLW0 |= UCSSEL__SMCLK;               // CLK = SMCLK
    UCA0BR0 = 8;                              // Clock prescaler set to 8
    UCA0BR1 = 0x00;                           // High byte empty, low byte is 8
    UCA0MCTLW |= UCOS16 | UCBRF_10 | 0xF700;  // Over-sampling on, first modulation register set to 10, second modulation register set to 0xF7 (247) for high byte, 0 for low byte
    UCA0CTLW0 &= ~UCSWRST;                    // Initialize eUSCI
    UCA0IE |= UCRXIE;                         // Enable USCI_A0 RX interrupt
}



//******************************************************************************
// Main ************************************************************************
//******************************************************************************

 int main(void)
 {
    WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;   // Stop watchdog timer
    //Initialize all peripherals
    initClockTo16MHz();
    initGPIO();
    UART_init();
    initI2C();

    bmi160_init('Z');

    int i = 0;

    //new
    TA0CTL   = TA0CTL | (SMCLK + CONTINUOUS);           // SMCLK:  Counts faster than ACLK
                                                        // CONTINUOUS:  Count 0 to 0xFFFF
    TA0CCTL0 = CCIE;                                    // Timer_0 interrupt

    TA1CTL   = TA1CTL | (ACLK  + UP         );          // Count up from 0 with ACLK
    TA1CCR0  = MS_10;                                   // Duration approximatley 10ms

    _BIS_SR(GIE);                                       // Activate all interrupts

    //new

    while(1)
    {
           printf("Reading samples\n");
           //Read SAMPLES amount of data from the BMI160
           for(i=0;i<SAMPLES;i++)
           {
               I2C_Master_ReadReg(SLAVE_ADDR, 0x16, 2); //Read the acceleration value from the BMI160 registers
               input[i]= ReceiveBuffer[0] | (ReceiveBuffer[1] << 8); //Store the value in an array
               printf("Sent acc: %u\n",(unsigned)input[i]);
           }
    }
}


//******************************************************************************
// Interrupts ******************************************************************
//******************************************************************************

//I2C Interrupt
#pragma vector = USCI_B1_VECTOR
__interrupt void USCI_B1_ISR(void)
{
  //Must read from UCB1RXBUF
  uint8_t rx_val = 0;
  switch(__even_in_range(UCB1IV, USCI_I2C_UCBIT9IFG))
  {
    case USCI_NONE:          break;         // Vector 0: No interrupts
    case USCI_I2C_UCALIFG:   break;         // Vector 2: ALIFG
    case USCI_I2C_UCNACKIFG:                // Vector 4: NACKIFG
      UCB1CTLW0 |= UCTXSTT;                 // Re-send start if NACK
      break;
    case USCI_I2C_UCSTTIFG:  break;         // Vector 6: STTIFG
    case USCI_I2C_UCSTPIFG:  break;         // Vector 8: STPIFG
    case USCI_I2C_UCRXIFG3:  break;         // Vector 10: RXIFG3
    case USCI_I2C_UCTXIFG3:  break;         // Vector 12: TXIFG3
    case USCI_I2C_UCRXIFG2:  break;         // Vector 14: RXIFG2
    case USCI_I2C_UCTXIFG2:  break;         // Vector 16: TXIFG2
    case USCI_I2C_UCRXIFG1:  break;         // Vector 18: RXIFG1
    case USCI_I2C_UCTXIFG1:  break;         // Vector 20: TXIFG1
    case USCI_I2C_UCRXIFG0:                 // Vector 22: RXIFG0
        rx_val = UCB1RXBUF;
        if (RXByteCtr)
        {
          ReceiveBuffer[ReceiveIndex++] = rx_val;
          RXByteCtr--;
        }

        if (RXByteCtr == 1)
        {
          UCB1CTLW0 |= UCTXSTP;
        }
        else if (RXByteCtr == 0)
        {
          UCB1IE &= ~UCRXIE;
          MasterMode = IDLE_MODE;
          __bic_SR_register_on_exit(CPUOFF);      // Exit LPM0
        }
        break;
    case USCI_I2C_UCTXIFG0:                 // Vector 24: TXIFG0
        switch (MasterMode)
        {
          case TX_REG_ADDRESS_MODE:
              UCB1TXBUF = TransmitRegAddr;
              if (RXByteCtr)
                  MasterMode = SWITCH_TO_RX_MODE;   // Need to start receiving now
              else
                  MasterMode = TX_DATA_MODE;        // Continue to transmision with the data in Transmit Buffer
              break;

          case SWITCH_TO_RX_MODE:
              UCB1IE |= UCRXIE;              // Enable RX interrupt
              UCB1IE &= ~UCTXIE;             // Disable TX interrupt
              UCB1CTLW0 &= ~UCTR;            // Switch to receiver
              MasterMode = RX_DATA_MODE;    // State state is to receive data
              UCB1CTLW0 |= UCTXSTT;          // Send repeated start
              if (RXByteCtr == 1)
              {
                  //Must send stop since this is the N-1 byte
                  while((UCB1CTLW0 & UCTXSTT));
                  UCB1CTLW0 |= UCTXSTP;      // Send stop condition
              }
              break;

          case TX_DATA_MODE:
              if (TXByteCtr)
              {
                  UCB1TXBUF = TransmitBuffer[TransmitIndex++];
                  TXByteCtr--;
              }
              else
              {
                  //Done with transmission
                  UCB1CTLW0 |= UCTXSTP;     // Send stop condition
                  MasterMode = IDLE_MODE;
                  UCB1IE &= ~UCTXIE;                       // disable TX interrupt
                  __bic_SR_register_on_exit(CPUOFF);      // Exit LPM0
              }
              break;

          default:
              __no_operation();
              break;
        }
        break;
    default: break;
  }
}



// Timer_0 Interrupt Service Routine
#pragma vector=TIMER0_A0_VECTOR
__interrupt void Timer_A0 (void)
{
    TA0CTL = TA0CTL & (~TAIFG);       // Reset Timer_0 so it keeps counting
}

